# Custom unique_ptr inside std::pair and standard collections

Tags: c++, templates, containers, template-meta-programming, std

I'm trying to use a custom `unique_ptr` inside a `std::pair` inside collections. Below is what I have so far, but if I uncomment the first commented-out line then I get an error:

> No matching constructor for initialization of PairedThing1

So I haven't gotten as far as putting these pairs in a container (the second commented-out line).

I've noted my intent in the comments. I'm seeking the right C++ incantation.

```cpp
template<class T> using UniqueThingRef = typename std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer_t<T>, void(*)(T)>;

typedef struct Thing1* Thing1Ref;
using PairedThing1 = std::pair<UniqueThingRef<Thing1Ref>, int>;

Thing1Ref MakeThing1()
{
    return (Thing1Ref)(new char()); //fake this for now
}

void KillThing1( Thing1Ref t)
{
    delete (char*)t; //fake this for now
}

static void trythings()
{
    UniqueThingRef<Thing1Ref> uni(MakeThing1(), KillThing1);
//  PairedThing1 duo(uni, 42); //uni should drop ref and hand to duo

    std::vector< PairedThing1> someThings;
//  someThings.insert( someThings.begin(), duo); //duo should drop ref and hand to someThings
}
```

Comment: confusing to read, as _ref_ != _pointer_ .

Comment: @JDługosz I know--it's out of context. I'm using this for Apple's CoreFoundation types (CGImageRef, CFStringRef, etc) which are all just pointers. Anyway that's why the "Ref" name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't copy a `std::unique_ptr` (hence the name). You have to move it.

```
PairedThing1 duo(uni, 42);
```

should be

```
PairedThing1 duo(std::move(uni), 42);
```

likewise the 2nd commented piece of code should be

```
someThings.insert(someThings.begin(), std::move(duo));
```